# ipa file size difference from jenkins xcode plugin and by xcode itself

Tags: xcode, jenkins

with the help of jenkins xcode plugin,I am creating a build of iOS project(ipa file).But I found a difference in the size of ipa from jenkins and one generated from the xcode workspace. Xcode Workspace generates the ipa file of 15 mb and one generated from jenkins is of 18 mb always.In my jenkins job I am just checking out the code and building ipa with the help of xcode plugin.Nothing else.
What could could be the reason for this 3 mb overhead any idea about this issue.

Comment: You could unzip the ipa and take a look at files inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on the stackoverflow,I found a solution. Here it is:

So when we create build from command line we should be taking care of `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=YES` parameter,which helps in stripping the binary.

> [iOS IPA file size - xcode-archive vs. xcodebuild command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650138/ios-ipa-file-size-xcode-archive-vs-xcodebuild-command)

More detail on [DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW53)